# Rocky Linux - Gnome Shell Integration extensions.gnome.org The add-on downloaded from this site could not be installed because it appears corrupt

Tags: firefox-extensions, gnome3, gnome-shell

I have a new installation of Rocky Linux Desktop Linux version 5.14.0-284.11.1.el9_2.x86_64 (mockbuild@iad1-prod-build001.bld.equ.rockylinux.org) (gcc (GCC) 11.3.1 20221121 (Red Hat 11.3.1-4), GNU ld version 2.35.2-37.el9) #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue May 9 17:09:15 UTC 2023

that has the Firefox Browser Extended Support Release 102.11.0esr (64-bit) Mozilla Firefox for Rocky Linux rocky-linux - 1.0 installed.

In my personal non-root account, I was able to go to the extensions.gnome.org webpage and install the Gnome Shell Integration application and then I was able to install a gnome extension called Dash to Panel successfully.

I then had another user go an attempt the same thing, however, on the initial installation of the Gnome Shell Integration, the page reports "extensions.gnome.org The add-on downloaded from this site could not be installed because it appears corrupt."

Any suggestions on how to get the Gnome Shell Integration installed on other accounts or why it would suddenly appear corrupt on installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution was worked out by switching to Google Chrome.  Once that was done, the Gnome Shell integration extension installed immediately.